# Is it logically valid to prove DeMorgan's laws using the duality of boolean algebra?

Tags: solution-verification, boolean-algebra, duality-theorems

I'm taking an introductory course in boolean algebra, and have been assigned the task of proving DeMorgan's Laws (so, disclaimer, this is homework). One line of reasoning I came up with is the following:

1. By applying the duality principle to two valued boolean algebra, $X \cdot Y = 1 \Leftrightarrow X + Y = 0$
2. $X+Y = 0 \Leftrightarrow \overline{X + Y} = 1$
3. Therefore, $X \cdot Y = 1 \Leftrightarrow \overline{X + Y} = 0$
4. By transitivity of equality, $X \cdot Y = \overline{X + Y}$

where $\cdot$ and $+$ are the conjunction and disjunction operators respectively.

**EDIT:** As pointed out by Lord_Farin, this result is incorrect, since the conclusion conflicts with DeMorgan's law. Where am I going wrong?

**Rest of original question:**

Now, the part I'm unsure about is the last step. Have I only managed to prove 4 in the specific case where the claim $X \cdot Y = 1$ is true, or is the proof valid regardless of whether $X \cdot Y = 0$? To my understanding, I have only made claims about *the implications* of  the statement, $X \cdot Y = 1$ but haven't actually claimed whether it is true or false.

Is there a flaw in this proof?

Comment: I originally posted this question on the cs.stackexchange site, but seeing as there are a number of questions (and tags) on boolean algebra here, it seems this site would be a better fit for it.

Comment: Well, De Morgan's law states that $\overline X\cdot\overline Y = \overline{X+Y}$, so you're bound to have a mistake somewhere...

Comment: @Lord_Farin You're right. That means my proof isn't even valid for the specific case. I can't spot the error though. edit: Actually, I'm probably just misinterpreting what the dual of a statement is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error results from misquoting the duality theorem. Let me state it for you here:

> If $T$ is a theorem about boolean algebras, then so is $T^*$, the statement obtained by carrying out the replacements $+ \leftrightarrow \cdot$ and $1 \leftrightarrow 0$.

But "$X\cdot Y =1$" is certainly not a theorem of BAs; it's contingent (it may be either true or false).

So while you can use duality to conclude the other part of De Morgan's laws:

- $\overline X \cdot \overline Y = \overline{X+Y}$
- $\overline X + \overline Y = \overline{X \cdot Y}$

when you've proven one of them (and in fact, duality is an elegant and efficient method to do it), it cannot be used to prove both of them.

Comment: What you're saying is true (i.e. 1 in my proof is obviously false simply from examining the truth tables of $X\cdot Y$ and $X + Y$), but descriptions of duality that I've seen speak of the dual of a *statement* and not a theorem. Example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_(category_theory). Is a statement equivalent to a theorem?

Comment: You can take the dual of any statement -- theorems are special cases of statements. The duality theorem states that the dual of a theorem is again a theorem. (Note the two different levels of "theorem" here!)

Comment: Is "theorem" synonymous with "true statement"? (I understand about the two levels, the dual theorem, which makes a claim about "theorems" in boolean algebra).

Comment: Yes. It's just mathematical lingo :).

Comment: In that case, we end up with "**If** statement S is a true statement, then S*, the dual of this statement, is also a true statement.". IOW, $S \Leftrightarrow S^*$. But clearly, if A and B are 1, then $A \cdot B = 1$ is a true statement. The dual of this true statement, i.e. $A + B = 0$ is not, however, true. This is what confuses me. (Sorry for trying your patience)

Comment: Similarly, for example, if A and B are 1 and 0, then the first statement is false, but its dual is true.

Comment: @Asad Sorry for confusing you. As pointed out, $A \cdot B = 1$ is not a "true statement", i.e., a "tautology". For, it could be that $A \cdot B = 1$ is *false*. There's two levels of "true" here: "true in a *particular* BA", or "true in *all* BAs". The latter sense of "true" goes by the name of "theorem". Note that the statement $A = B = 1 \to A \cdot B = 1$ *is* true in all BAs; hence, so is $A = B = 0 \to A + B = 0$.

Comment: Ah, that makes perfect sense!

Comment: I'm glad I could be of help to you!